# Most Efficient way to find value in JSON . jsonpath.read vs jackson findvalue?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonpath

I have my JSON data stored in JsonNode. Which is the most efficient way to search for a field in this JsonNode?

1. JsonNode.findValue() or I should use Jsonpath .read()
2. Is JsonNode.findValue() internally de marshalling JSON to POJOs for finding specified value.

Which way is better. Please help.

Comment: The *fastest* way is probably using regex to match your target.

Comment: But one consideration is, I have data in JsonNode. JsonPath.read() requires input JSON to be a string . I need to convert my data to a string for using JsonPath.read(). Will using JsonPath.read() be still quicker ??

Comment: @anuragmishra - Converting back to string and then parsing again won't certainly NOT be the most efficient way. If you have JsonNode, you can create a simple tree traversal to search for a field in that JSON tree.  
Either way -  If you want to find the most efficient, then simply try both and measure.